# How to work with Interlization concept in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project i am using Interlization by using spring mvc it's Working fine .But I want to show some alret() message to end user according to Selected Language .How i do this any one help me.I am using **hidden Fields** in my view layer but some performance issue is occur so any way to read **properties file data by using javascript or jQuery**

Comment: You're missing 7 characters in `i18n` :)

Comment: what is Interlization?

Comment: Look up the messages on the server and either have it write some javascript into the page (in a `<script>` tag) or make an ajax call to the server to get one or several messages or have some javascript files with messages in them in form `var msg1="Bob is in trouble in spanish";` such that when you load that script, the server gives you the right language/country version of the file.

Comment: "Javascript or jQuery"? That's kind of like saying you want to have either beef or a burger for dinner.

Comment: @MattEllen [It's probably "internalization"](https://www.google.com/#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=9f60335c8140cdcf&q=spring+mvc+internalization).

Comment: @AndersonGreen yeah, probably. I thought it might be a framework or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested objects. For example:

```
// Init a dictionary
var messages = {
    en : {},
    es : {}
};

// Populate
messages.en['welcome'] = 'welcome';
messages.es['welcome'] = 'bienvenido';

// Test    
var lang = 'es';
alert(messages[lang]['welcome']);
```